# How does the tmux color palette work?

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to set something to gray, but can't figure out how. The only bit of info in the man page about colors I can find is:

```
message-bg colour
  Set status line message background colour, where colour is one of:
  black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white, colour0 to
  colour255 from the 256-colour palette, or default.
```

I also found [a blog post](http://blog.yjl.im/2011/02/tmux-clock-mode-as-working-pain.html) which iterates through colors, but I can't quite grok it, and don't want to sit at the terminal all day guessing color numbers until one works.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

You can get a list with this `bash` snippet:

```
for i in {0..255}; do
    printf "\x1b[38;5;${i}mcolour${i}\x1b[0m\n"
done
```

Then use `colourxxx` with `tmux`.

Comment: perhaps you need three digit colours? This script outputs like `color12` but that is not accepted by tmux as a valid colour.

Comment: My `tmux` (1.6) accepts even colors like `colour12` (mind the "u").

Comment: @cYrus starting with 3.2, `tmux` also supports `color12` (without the "u")

Answer (score 152):

I found this image to be enlightening.

[image]

Comment: You can create it with `for i in {0..255}; do  printf "\x1b[38;5;${i}mcolor%-5i\x1b[0m" $i ; if ! (( ($i + 1 ) % 8 )); then echo ; fi ; done`

Comment: An alternative output that groups the colors after `colour15` is generated with `for i in {0..255}; do  printf "\x1b[38;5;${i}mcolor%-5i\x1b[0m" $i ; if ! (( ($i - 3) % 6 )); then echo ; fi ; done`.

Answer (score 26):

In Subversion (what will be tmux 1.5) you can also use #abcdef hex-style colours which are mapped to the nearest 256 colour palette entry. You need quotes as it's treated as a string, whereas regular color names are treated as named constants. Also note that 3-letter shorthand (#f00) is invalid.

Example:

```
set pane-active-border-bg red # no quotes for name
set pane-active-border-bg "#ff0000" # quotes for rgb
```

Comment: Can you? I can't see how to...

Comment: set-option message-bg "#abcdef"; the quotes are necessary.

Comment: You also seem to have to use the full 6 hex chars, no 3 char shortcuts i.e. `#fff` will not work, you have to use `#ffffff`

Answer (score 20):

Before tmux 3.2 (released in April 2021), tmux only supported the international (British) spelling for the 256 colour palette, e.g.

```
"colour121"
```

as opposed to the [American spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-our,_-or) that drops the `u`

```
"color121"
```

If you're using tmux 3.2 or later, you can spell it either way.

Answer (score 8):

Building up on @cYrus' answer, I wrote a script to break the output of the colors into N number of columns, where N is the first argument

`# colors.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    BREAK=4
else
    BREAK=$1
fi
for i in {0..255} ; do
    printf "\x1b[38;5;${i}mcolour${i} \t"
    if [ $(( i % $BREAK )) -eq $(($BREAK-1)) ] ; then
        printf "\n"
    fi
done
```

Try it by saving it into a file called colors.sh, then `./colors.sh 4`

Don't forget to `chmod +x colors.sh` first.

Comment: Script [show-256-colors.sh](https://gist.github.com/ivanbrennan/8ce10a851851e5f04728d8da900ef1c5) can be useful to show background colors as well.

Comment: You ought to default it to say, at least 4 columns, to distinguish it from the origin script.

Answer (score 7):

I've been using the [xterm-color-table.vim](https://github.com/guns/xterm-color-table.vim/blob/master/README.markdown) script. Any 256 color terminal color table will work.

Answer (score 0):

I find this function producing the most concise and clear output (it's not mine):

```
colors () {
    for i in {0..255}
    do
        print -Pn "%K{$i}  %k%F{$i}${(l:3::0:)i}%f " ${${(M)$((i%6)):#3}:+$'\n'}
    done
}
```

[image: function output screenshot]

Then you use `colourXXX` where XXX is the three digits code printed above as the value for `fg=`, `bg=` etc...

Comment: Suggestion: note this script requires zsh.