# Using gray color in tmux status bar

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

I am using iterm2 on mac os x and I can't get something like color245 to show up as gray, seems like tmux uses black instead. I am using iterm2 on mac os x. Any idea what might be wrong?

setw -g window-status-bg colour245

I used the script from the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/285381/how-does-the-tmux-color-palette-work) and I can verify that colour245 appears as gray. I am a tmux newbie. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug, status-bg works fine but the 256-colour flag appears to be lost from window-status-bg. Please report to nicm at users dot sf dot net or the tmux-users mailing list.